# Why does fast-forwarding with git fetch reject an ahead branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fetch, fast-forward

To fast-forward from origin I can do `git merge --ff-only origin/BR` if BR is checked out, otherwise `git fetch . origin/BR:BR` (or `git fetch origin BR:BR` to also update origin/BR).

Using `git merge`, if `BR` is ahead of origin, I get "already up-to-date". Using `git fetch`, I get "rejected (non-fast-forward)". Why is this?

Comment: Context: this is my alias for accomplishing the equivalent of "switch to develop, pull, switch back". I'm unlikely to push to local develop (especially if I'm also making feature or bugfix branches), so it's unlikely to come up, but I'm curious anyway. `git config --global alias.pulld \!"git fetch && git fetch . origin/develop:develop"`

Comment: Ask `git status` while on that branch. It will tell you ahead/behind.

Comment: @Guildenstern I'm asking why fast-forwarding an ahead branch yields different results when fast-forwarding by `merge` vs `fetch`.

Comment: Better version of the alias (defaults to develop but allows argument): `git config --global alias.pullb '!git fetch && git fetch . origin/${1-develop}:${1-develop} #'`